# Adding Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, bids, sql-server-2014

I have a current instance of SQL Server 2014 on my machine and just installed Visual Studio 2013. I would like to install BIDS as well. Unfortunately I keep getting an error and I do not really understand why. Would anyone be able to help?

[image]

I am assuming I would want to use the same installation, but I am not really sure what could be going wrong. Any help or information would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: On a previous setup page named "Installation Type" you should have selected the "Perform a new installation" option instead on selecting the "Add features to an existing instance" option.

Comment: @knkarthick24 - I came across that solution over the weekend, but that did it thanks!